# Write a program in C to display the n terms of even and odd natural number and their sum using functions

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_even(int n);
int sum_odd(int m);

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int m;
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int evensum;
    evensum = sum_even(int n);

    int oddsum;
    oddsum = sum_odd(int m);

    printf("the sum of even numbers is %d", evensum);
    printf("the sum of odd numbers is %d", oddsum);

    return 0;
}

int sum_even(int n) {
    int sum = 0, i;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int sum_odd(int m) {
    int SUM = 0, j;
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j = j + 2) {
        SUM = SUM + j;
    }
    return SUM;
}
```

please tell me what is wrong with my code, I am new to coding, I am able to solve questions without using functions but I am confused when I have to use functions

Comment: `evensum = sum_even(int n) ;` Make that just `evensum = sum_even(n) ;`. You don't repeat the type when you *call* a function, the compiler already knows that `int n ;` is an integer.

Comment: If the previous comment does not solve your problem then please clarify what the error or incorrect result is that you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While calling functions you just pass the arguments and not specify its data type.

i.e. You would write it like this :-

```
evensum = sum_even(n);
oddsum = sum_odd(m);
```

The general syntax of calling a function which returns a value is :-

```
return-value = function-name(arg-list);
```

Comment: If you have any other doubts please add it below in the comments.